Perforce stream - can you share a whole directory but import specific directories in that root directory?
I want to do something like that
import ...
share source/...
import source/3rdparty/...

Such a spec doesn't work for me. How do I fall 3rdparty directory back to import behaviour without explicitly listing every other subdirectory from source/?
Similar but different Perforce stream - can you exclude a directory but include specific files in that directory?

Oh, I missed /... part in my stream view, it works
